# Put a "Start" button in Google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, button, spreadsheet

I am very a newbie at programming...

I want to insert a button called "Start" in my Google spreadsheet and when I click on it, I want that the date and time at that very moment go in another cell.
So the function NOW() should be running and the value of it to be put in another cell...
not sure I'm perfectly clear though...
Please find attached an image that show how that would work.

Thank you so much for you help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Yyf.png)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't really use google docs in that way. The more complicated answer is that you'll need to build an add-on through app scripting: https://developers.google.com/apps-script

Google states that their intended replacement of the ui scripting is now html:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

so in other words, to make that button, you'll need to make an apps-script add-on and put that in your spreadsheet.

I'm not actually in a place where I can check, but there used to be an insert menu where you could put an empty button-looking object on the sheet, then you might be able to attach a more simplified script to that object. If that isn't around anymore, you'll have to go the apps-script direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an Apps Script function to an image or drawing in Google Sheets, so long as the script is bound to the spreadsheet. The example below shows how to set this up.

1. In Google Sheets, select the menu item Tools > Script editor to
   create a script that is bound to the spreadsheet.
2. Paste in the code below.

> ```
>  function startDate() { 
>      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(),
>           cell = 1,
>           col = 1,
>           cellC = 1,
>           colC = 1,
>           rowData = new Date,
>           pasteTo = sheet.getRange(cell, col,cellC,colC).setValue(rowData); 
>  }
> ```

3. Return to Sheets and insert an image or drawing by selecting Insert > Image or
   Insert > Drawing.
4. After inserting the image or drawing, click it. A
   small drop-down menu selector will appear in the top right-hand
   corner. Click it and choose Assign script.
5. In the dialog box that appears, type the name of the Apps Script function 
   that you want to run, without parentheses — in this case, startDate. Click OK.
6. Click the image or drawing again. The function will now execute.

Answer (score -1):

Please find [here](http://hpics.li/b21d5ca) the document i'm using for now.

I definitely think I can improve that, because the problem with those multiple buttons is that my co-workers have to "authorize" the script each time the click on "Start" or "Stop", and that for all the projects.
So each time a select a task and click start button, it creates a new line in another tab with "Task", "Start time", "End time"

My ultimate goal would be to have a page with only 3 things
- the list of tasks 
- START button
- STOP button

http://hpics.li/cc882f1